# One Product, Multiple Categories (one to many) too many rows on table

Tags: postgresql, database-design

So I'm developing an e-commerce website, and I have a product with many categories.

So my concern is, what if I have 1000 products and each of them has 5 categories, so is it unavoidable to have 5000 rows on my table whereas I only have 1000 products? Or is there any other way to implement it? I'm using postgresql for my database.

My simplified table structures:

products table

```
| id | item_code | category_id |
```

category table

```
| id | description |
```

Comment: What's the problem with 5000 rows? This is considered extremely tiny these days. I usually don't start performance testing with less than a million rows.

Comment: Don't you think you need a third table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a third table which will hold the `ProductId` and the `CategoryId`, both are a `PRIMARY KEY` (composite primary key).

So your tables will be like:

**Products table:** *ProductId PK*

```
+-----------+-----------+
| ProductId | item_code |
+-----------+-----------+
|           |           |
+-----------+-----------+
```

**Categories table:** *CategoryId PK*

```
+------------+-------------+
| CategoryId | Description |
+------------+-------------+
|            |             |
+------------+-------------+
```

**ProductCategories table:**

*ProductId, CategoryId PK*

*ProductId FK Reference Products(ProductId)*

*CategoryId FK Reference Categories(CategoryId)*

```
+-----------+------------+
| ProductId | CategoryId |
+-----------+------------+
|           |            |
+-----------+------------+
```

Colnclusion:

```
+-------------------+------------+-------+-----------------+------------------+
|     TableName     | ColumnName | Kind  | ReferencedTable | ReferencedColumn |
+-------------------+------------+-------+-----------------+------------------+
| Products          | ProductId  | PK    |                 |                  |
| Categories        | CategoryId | PK    |                 |                  |
| ProductCategories | ProductId  | PK/FK | Products        | ProductId        |
| ProductCategories | CategoryId | PK/FK | Categories      | CategoryId       |
+-------------------+------------+-------+-----------------+------------------+
```

Comment: Note that in Postgres you could also use an array for the categories.  That makes the schema simpler, but it comes at a price (namely there are chances it will be less efficient when querying, and a bit cumbersome when updating).